# Convert UTC datetime to local datetime in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

In my PowerBI data source (table storage), I have a DateTime column which contains a UTC DateTime. I'm looking to convert this to the local datetime. Specifically, I also want to take into account Daylight Savings Time as well.

I have found several solutions online, but none of them takes into account DST. Anyone able to give me some pointers?

The timezone I want the user to see is UTC+2 (Belgium/Brussels).

Preferably to see in PowerBI desktop, mobile & on the website

Comment: I'm not sure there is a handy solution. Which local time zone is the one you want the user to see and on which interface (Power BI Desktop, Power BI Service website, Power BI mobile app, Power BI Windows Universal app)?

Comment: @TomBlodget I have clarified this in the question. Thank you.

Comment: You could always convert it manually using DAX formulas.

Comment: Agree with @user5226582. The "headquarters office" timezone case is the most solvable. (The user location, preference and "local office" cases are much harder.) If all of your dates are [1978](ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdb-2017b/europe)[See Brussels] or later and you aren't concerned with the potential for future DST rule changes, I think the solution is to hard-code it in some formulas.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be the case. I'm now considering to update my code to add an additional column in my data store, to also use the local datetime. Such a pity this is not supported some way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this old question, since I found this question as a first hit in a search and it is very common and often asked question. Note that this applies mostly to data sources that are "implicitly" assuming UTC but not storing this information with the row/field values, such as a SQL-Server source with "DateTime" columns.

For *querying* data, thus *reading* from a table, you can do this:

This approach is dynamically considering the timezone by client (user local timezone) and thus also *automatically* taking DST into account is as follows:

You need to create a custom column in the "Query Editor" and need to add *two* more *custom* columns for each original column (click "Add custom column"):

- One that takes timezone "UTC" as baseline and stores it for each entry. This is only necessary if your column does not carry it already. The formula is: "DateTime.AddZone([Time],0)"
- One that then stores the converted local-timezone value (from the client at query/import time (!)). The formula to use is: "DateTimeZone.SwitchZone([ZoneTime],[UTC])"

This is not a beautiful way of doing this for large and complex data structures (with many tables). Thus an alternative solution is using "Dataflow" utilities from the PowerBI ecosystem to convert data in a stream like manner before using them in reports. In such a flow you add the timezone "UTC" column (step 1) before digesting it in Power BI.